# Access violation reading location 0x00000000 cstrings

Tags: c++, access-violation, cstring

From reading other stackoverflow questions I am aware that this error means I am trying to dereference a null pointer. However, I cannot figure out where my code is dereferencing a null pointer. I am trying to set a char* (cstring) to a non-null value, but I get an access violation error. Here is the code:

```
void Data::setName(char const * const name)
{
    if (this->name)
        delete[] this->name;

    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];    // This is where my code breaks in debug mode
    strcpy(this->name, name);
}
```

name is a char* variable that gets initialized to null. setName is being called by an overloaded assignment operator:

```
Data& Data::operator=(const Data& data2)
{
    //if it is a self copy, don't do anything
    if (this == &data2)
        return *this;

    else
    {
        setName(data2.name);    // Here is the call to setName
        return *this;
    }
}
```

P.S. For the love of god please don't tell me I shouldn't be using cstrings! I know std::string is better, but this is for a homework assignment that requires cstrings.

Comment: Please post your entire class, plus the main() program you use to test this.  Otherwise, all we have are two functions that have no  logical errors (but have other issues).

Comment: In addition: `if (this->name)`  This is not necessary.  There is no need to check for nullptr or NULL when issuing a call to `delete[]`.  Also, what if I pass a null pointer to `setName`?  Your program will have undefined behavior, since strlen(0) is UB.

Comment: "Also, what if I pass a null pointer to setName?" That is exactly what my problem was!

Comment: ok.  But what do you do if a null pointer is passed?  You can ignore it and let the program possibly crash (which is what std::string does).

Comment: "For the love of god please don't tell me I shouldn't be using cstrings!" -- I think you should go into your professor office, tell him/her that, unless the assignment is to implement `std::string`, you *are* going to use `std::string`. Remember to maintain eye contact the whole time.

Comment: @chillpenguin The ironic thing is that professors that say "don't use std::string" are basically telling their students to produce buggy programs.  The reason I say that is that I have yet to see anyone claiming to be a beginner or student C++ programmer create a bug-free string class.  The goal of writing a program is to make sure it's bug free, and asking you to use cstrings guarantees your program is not bug free (unless you get an experienced person on SO to write it for you).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know but it's not my decision. Talk with my professor about it. I just think it's funny that I specifically said I know std::string is better, but I have to use cstrings. I specifically said that so people wouldn't try to tell me all about how dumb it is to use cstrings. Trust me I know already. But there's nothing I can do about it. When I write my own programs not for school, I will use std::string. But my homework requires cstrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the line the code breaks:

```
this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
```

then `name` must be a null pointer, since **nothing else is being dereferenced**. `name` is being dereferenced inside the `strlen` function. Just print the variable value in your debugger and you will be sure.

---

Also, using same name of variable in the setter like this:

```
struct A
{
    void set(int a){this->a = a;}
    int a;
};
```

is not a good practice. Just use:

```
struct A
{
    void set(int na){a = na;}
    int a;
};
```

or

```
struct A
{
    void set(int a){a_ = a;}
    int a_;
};
```

Comment: Wow you were right. Looks like I have a new bug to fix since that shouldn't have happened... I'll accept your answer once stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @chillpenguin - You know that passing a NULL pointer to `std::string` is undefined behavior, in other words, you may have crashed anyway even if you used `std::string`.  So maybe you shouldn't fix your `Data` class.  What you should fix is the code using the `Data` class.

Comment: +1.. nice job with answering the question, and going a step further by providing the OP some healthy code alternatives!

Comment: The "not good practice" part of your answer is something that is built in to my homework assignment and I can't change it. I can only change the .cpp files, not the .h files. In the .h file the function declaration (with arguments) and member variables of the class were already there. It is my instructor that is using the same names for member variables and function arguments...